# Definition of Morphisms of algebraic stacks smooth of relative dimension n

Tags: algebraic-stacks, smoothness

There is a notion of smooth morphism of algebraic stacks e.g.  [Tag 075U](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/075U) and a notion of 
relative dimension of a locally of finite type morphism $T\to \mathcal{X}$ from an algebraic space into an algebraic stack e.g. [Tag 0DRG](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0DRG).

In the case of locally Noetherian algebraic stacks, there is also a notion of relative dimension of a locally of finite type morphism $\mathcal{T}\to \mathcal{X}$ between algebraic stacks e.g. [Tag 0DRL](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0DRL).

What is the (commonly used) definition of a locally of finite type morphism between (locally Noetherian) algebraic stacks being **"smooth of relative dimension $n$"**?

The most natural approach would be to define it as being a smooth morphism such that the relative dimension in every point is $n$. However I couldn't find this definition anywhere in the literature.

Another possible Definition that I can think about is to follow the definition of smoothness given in stacks project:
A locally of finite type morphism of algebraic stacks $\mathcal{X}\to \mathcal{Y}$ is called **"smooth of relative dimension $n$"** if and only if there is a commutative diagram
$$\begin{array}{c} U & \overset{h}{\rightarrow} & V \\ \overset{a}{}\downarrow && \overset{b}{}\downarrow \\ \mathcal{X} & \overset{f}{\rightarrow} & \mathcal{Y}  \end{array}$$, where $U,V$ are algebraic spaces with smooth vertical arrows such that $U\to \mathcal{X}\times_{\mathcal{Y}} V$ is smooth and $a$ surjective, such that $h$ is smooth of relative dimension $n$.
Compare [Tag 06FM](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/06FM). In this case one would need to define what it means for a morphism of algebraic spaces to be smooth of relative dimension $n$ using a similar commutative diagram with etale vertical arrows, as is done in stacks project for smoothness of morphisms of algebraic spaces [Tag 03ZC](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/03ZC).

Another possible definition that I can think of is using a presentation $[U/R]\to \mathcal{X}$.

Is there a commonly used definition for the notion of smooth of relative dimension $n$ morphisms of algebraic stacks?

Thank You for Your help.

Comment: Excuse me if this is a bad question. I am only a graduate master student, not an expert at all.

Comment: You cannot follow the definition given in the stacks project directly, because the property "relative dimension $n$" is not smooth local on source-and-target.  In particular, this property is not stable under precomposing with smooth maps (condition 1 in https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/06F8), because the relative dimension may change.